# Contact form not working with Bootstrap+PHP

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to send an email via HTML5 with bootstrap + php.

HTML:

```
<form name="frmContacto" class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="mail/contact_me.php">
    <fieldset>
        <legend class="text-center header">Formulario de contacto</legend>

        <div class="form-group">
            <span class="col-md-1 col-md-offset-2 text-center"><i class="fa fa-user bigicon"></i></span>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <input id="fname" name="name" type="text" placeholder="Nombre" class="form-control">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <span class="col-md-1 col-md-offset-2 text-center"><i class="fa fa-user bigicon"></i></span>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <input id="lname" name="name" type="text" placeholder="Apellidos" class="form-control">
            </div>
       </div>

       <div class="form-group">
           <span class="col-md-1 col-md-offset-2 text-center"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o bigicon"></i></span>
           <div class="col-md-8">
                <input id="email" name="email" type="text" placeholder="Correo electrónico" class="form-control">
           </div>
       </div>

       <div class="form-group">
           <span class="col-md-1 col-md-offset-2 text-center"><i class="fa fa-phone-square bigicon"></i></span>
           <div class="col-md-8">
               <input id="phone" name="phone" type="text" placeholder="Teléfono" class="form-control">
           </div>
       </div>

       <div class="form-group">
           <span class="col-md-1 col-md-offset-2 text-center"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o bigicon"></i></span>
           <div class="col-md-8">
                <textarea class="form-control" id="message" name="message" placeholder="Introduce aquí tu mensaje." rows="7"></textarea>
           </div>
       </div>

       <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                <a href="mailto:xxx@example.com?Subject=Hello%20again" target="_top">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Enviar</button>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
// Check for empty fields
if (empty($_POST['name']) ||
    empty($_POST['email']) ||
    empty($_POST['phone']) ||
    empty($_POST['message']) ||
    !filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)
) {
    echo "No arguments Provided!";
    return false;
}

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email_address = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

// Create the email and send the message
$to = 'xxx@gmail.com'; // Add your email address inbetween the '' replacing yourname@yourdomain.com - This is where the form will send a message to.
$email_subject = "Formulario de contacto web:  $name";
$email_body = "Ha recibido un nuevo mensaje desde la web.\n\n" . "Detalles:\n\Nombre: $name\n\nEmail: $email_address\n\Teléfono: $phone\n\Mensaje:\n$message";
$headers = "From: noreply@yourdomain.com\n"; // This is the email address the generated message will be from. We recommend using something like noreply@yourdomain.com.
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address";
mail($to, $email_subject, $email_body, $headers);
return true;
?>
```

I don't know if I have to import something in the HTML. It seems that the php mail() function is not being called, since I have a breakpoint in the function line and nothing happens when I click the "Submit" button. Also, the email is the same in $to php function and in the HTML "mailto".

Thanks a lot.

Comment: have you configured your sendmail.ini

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the following things-
1. In your HTML you have declared Name Line of form twice, which is not required.
2. You should have setting in your server/PHP configuration file configured to a mail Server. Without Mail server connected, you can't send mails

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's the issue. However, I need to configure my XAMPP to work with JetBrains PHP Storm, I'm investigating how to do that. It's needed to configure this on my hosting service too, it's automatic, or it depends on each hosting? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you validate your settings in php.ini (sendmail parameter) ?

You might read this if needed:
https://blog.codinghorror.com/so-youd-like-to-send-some-email-through-code/

Comment: I use XAMPP, but I don't know how to configure it to work with JetBrains PHP Storm, and I don't know if I have to configure this in my hosting service once the web is uploaded (I see not php.ini in my hosting service).

Answer (score 0):

The Code is below is well commented so there is no point writing much. Just read through the Comments. It is quite self-explanatory:

**PHP**

```
    <?php

        // GET ALL POSTED FIELD-VALUES AND ASSIGN THEM DEFAULT VALUES OF NULL (IF THEY ARE NOT YET SET...
        $lastName   = isset($_POST['last_name'])    ? htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['last_name']))   : null;
        $firstName  = isset($_POST['first_name'])   ? htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['first_name']))  : null;
        $email      = isset($_POST['email'])        ? htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['email']))       : null;
        $phone      = isset($_POST['phone'])        ? htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['phone']))       : null;
        $message    = isset($_POST['message'])      ? htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['message']))     : null;

        // VALIDATE THE FIELDS: BUT FIRST CREATE AN ARRAY
        // TO HOLD ERROR MESSAGES FOR FIELDS THAT FAILED THE VALIDATION.
        $arrErrorBag        = array();
        $strErrorMessage    = "";

        // VALIDATE E-MAIL:
        if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            $arrErrorBag["E-Mail"]      = "The Email you entered in not valid.";
        }

        // VALIDATE FIRST NAME:
        if(!preg_match('#(^[a-zA-z])?([\w\.\-\ ])*\w*$#i', $firstName)){
            $arrErrorBag["First Name"] = "First Name Should not be Empty and should contain only alpha-numeric Characters.";
        }

        // VALIDATE LAST NAME:
        if(!preg_match('#(^[a-zA-z])?([\w\.\-\ ])*\w*$#i', $lastName)){
            $arrErrorBag["Last Name"] = "Last Name Should not be Empty and should contain only alpha-numeric Characters.";
        }

        // VALIDATE PHONE:
        if(!preg_match('#^(\+\d{1,3})?\s?(\d{2,4})\s?(\d{2,4})\s?(\d{2,4})\s?(\d{2,4})$#', $phone)){
            $arrErrorBag["Phone"]       = "Telephone Number should be Numeric and Should not be Empty.";
        }

        // VALIDATE MESSAGE:
        if(!preg_match('#([\w\.\-\d\ ])*\w*$#si', $name)){
            $arrErrorBag["Message"]     = "Message Should not be Empty and should contain only alpha-numeric Characters only.";
        }

        if(!empty($arrErrorBag)){
            // WE HAVE SOME ERRORS SO WE BUILD A STRING MESSAGE BASED ON THE ERRORS WE HAVE GATHERED ABOVE...
            $strErrorMessage     .= "<h6 class='error-heading'>There are Errors in the Form Please, correct them to continue.</h6>";
            foreach($arrErrorBag as $fieldName=>$errorMessage){
                $strErrorMessage .= "<div class='error-block'><strong>{$fieldName}: </strong>";
                $strErrorMessage .= "<span>{$errorMessage}: </span></div>";
            }
        }else{
            // THE FORM IS CLEAN AND VALID SO WE SEND THE E-MAIL:
            $name           = $firstName . " " . $lastName;
            $to             = 'xxx@gmail.com'; // Add your email address inbetween the '' replacing yourname@yourdomain.com - This is where the form will send a message to.
            $email_subject  = "Formulario de contacto web:  $name";
            $email_body     = "Ha recibido un nuevo mensaje desde la web.\n\n" . "Detalles:\n\Nombre: {$name}\n\nEmail: {$email}\n\Teléfono: {$phone}\n\Mensaje:\n{$message}";
            $headers        = "From: noreply@yourdomain.com\n"; // This is the email address the generated message will be from. We recommend using something like noreply@yourdomain.com.
            $headers       .= "Reply-To: {$email}";
            mail($to, $email_subject, $email_body, $headers);

            // THE MAIL WAS SENT SO YOU CAN NOW REDIRECT TO ANOTHER PAGE... MAYBE A THANK YOU PAGE...
            $redirectURL        = "thank-you.php";      //<== THIS IS ONLY AN EXAMPLE... THE URL SHOULD RATHER BE ANY PAGE OF YOUR CHOOSING.
            header("location: " . $redirectURL);
        }

    ?>
```

**HTML**

```
    <!-- BEFORE THE FORM, CREATE A DIV TO HOLD ERROR MESSAGE, IN CASE ERRORS OCCUR... -->
    <!-- IN THIS SCENARIO, IT IS IDEAL TO HAVE BOTH THE PHP AND THE HTML INSIDE THE SAME FILE... -->
    <!-- THE PHP CODE SHOLD BE AT THE TOP OF THE FILE & THE HTML MARKUP BELOW... -->
    <!-- NOTICE THAT THE ACTION ATTRIBUTE OF THE FORM IS NOW EMPTY... THIS FORCES THE FORM TO SUBMIT BACK TO ITSELF: THIS PAGE... -->
    <div class="error-msg-wrapper"><?php echo $strErrorMessage; ?></div>
    <form name="frmContacto" class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="">
        <fieldset>
            <legend class="text-center header">Formulario de contacto</legend>

            <div class="form-group">
                <span class="col-md-1 col-md-offset-2 text-center">
                    <i class="fa fa-user bigicon"></i>
                </span>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <input id="fname" name="first_name" type="text" placeholder="Nombre" value="<?php echo $firstName; ?>" class="form-control">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <span class="col-md-1 col-md-offset-2 text-center">
                    <i class="fa fa-user bigicon"></i>
                </span>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <input id="lname" name="last_name" type="text" placeholder="Apellidos"  value="<?php echo $lastName; ?>" class="form-control">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <span class="col-md-1 col-md-offset-2 text-center">
                    <i class="fa fa-envelope-o bigicon"></i>
                </span>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <input id="email" name="email" type="text" placeholder="Correo electrónico" value="<?php echo $email; ?>" class="form-control">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <span class="col-md-1 col-md-offset-2 text-center">
                    <i class="fa fa-phone-square bigicon"></i>
                </span>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <input id="phone" name="phone" type="text" placeholder="Teléfono" value="<?php echo $phone; ?>" class="form-control">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <span class="col-md-1 col-md-offset-2 text-center">
                    <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o bigicon"></i>
                </span>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <textarea class="form-control" id="message" name="message" placeholder="Introduce aquí tu mensaje." rows="7"><?php echo $message; ?></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" value="Enviar" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
```